# format structure of a ms word document

Tags: pdf, ms-word, rtf

I have converted a well structured pdf document into a rich text format.

By Structured document I mean the document has well formatted heading levels, bullets and numberings, and sections, and also has contents table.

After conversion from pdf, the rich text file appears almost exactly similar to the original pdf document, but the formatting data is not available in the document. Heading levels and numberings are not available in outline view of the ms word. the numberings seems to be a plain text typed one after another. they do not behave like  a normal ms word numbering which increments automatically for every new line. Similarly for bullets and headings. they do not form a structure of sections.

for eg: when I select a bullet character, the bullet characters of the same group should be highlighted. instead only the bullet character which I select gets highlighted.

It is a document with 200+ pages. I need to apply styles and formatting supported by MS word by default. Kindly help in finding a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I used MS Office 2013 to convert the PDF into rich text and it worked fine. It retained almost all of the heading information and table structure. Even though I had to apply some manual formatting, it is by far a well formatted conversion I have used.